# Why optional chaining is required in the following case if the variable type is not declare explicitly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following extension

```
extension UIWindow {
    static var key: UIWindow! {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        }
    }
}
```

I can use it without optional chaining in the following case

### Case 1

```
UIWindow.key.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer())
```

### Case 2

```
let key: UIWindow = UIWindow.key
key.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer())
```

But, when use it in the following case, I will get a compiler error

### Case 3 (Not working)

```
let key = UIWindow.key
// value of optional type 'UIWindow?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'addGestureRecognizer' of wrapped base type 'UIWindow'
key.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer())
```

May I know why it is so? Why the compiler cannot recognise `key` as `UIWindow`, without having programmer to declare its type explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is introduced in [SE-054: Abolish `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md). The point is to limit the use of implicitly unwrapped optionals.

As the proposal describes:

> If the expression can be explicitly type checked with a strong optional type, it will be.

So the "explicitly" unwrapped optional is always preferred, when no other information is provided. The `key` in `let key = UIWindow.key` is of type `UIWindow?`.

It's only when you, e.g. provide an explicit type annotation `: UIWindow`, that the right hand side being of type `UIWindow?` won't typecheck anymore, and so the compiler has to implicitly unwrap the `UIWindow!`.

The rationale is:

> This model is more predictable because it prevents IUOs from propagating implicitly through the codebase, and converts them to strong optionals, the safer option, by default.